# My URL is not open properly

Tags: php, dns, hosting, meta

I have release my website on fozzy hosting services still my website home page and other pages not open properly.

I have already clear cache, also open incognito mode, change the header meta information, also checked the menu linking but not open properly.

Website URL:- http://weddingscope.in/

Can any one have any answer then its appriciated

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question really is about... ???

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "*my website home page and other pages not open properly*"

Comment: Looks like the links cause a server error, which can't be resolved without knowing the tech stack and relevant error logs.

Comment: It appears to work now. How'd you fix it? Or did it just start working?

Comment: Thanks all of you now my url is open properly